# Serve django-admin with tornado

Tags: python, django, django-admin, tornado

My setup consists of a Django web application + Django admin served by Tornado.

Serving Django works fine except for Django admin. When I open `http://localhost:8000/admin` I only see HTML without any CSS.
Fetching admin assets results in a 404.

My configured routes:

```
application = WSGIHandler()
container = WSGIContainer(application)

tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
        EchoSockjsRouter('/websocket').urls+
        [
            (r"/public/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "static/"}),
            ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=container)),
        ])
```

My assumption was, that all assets for Django admin are also served by the `FallbackHandler`.
If not, what do I need to do to also have admin assets served properly?

Comment: I am facing the same problem too